# Multiple rsync into same destination?

Tags: synchronization, backup, rsync, file-storage

I'm using different computers to edit media and I'd like to make them backup their material automatically.

For that I thought a cronjob with rsync might be nice.

What happens if there are conflicting files / race conditions?

For example:

Computer1 rsync -va /bla/photos/ -> NAS:/photos/
Computer2 rsync -va /otherbla/photos/ -> NAS:/photos/

Lets say they both contain 'test.jpg' and happen to trigger the cronjob at the same time. If computer1 is sending the image, what will happen to computer2? An Error? Will it just wait?

I know it would be possible to create different destinations, but it was nice if they could backup into my existing archive without me needing to push things around later.

If two rsyncs are a bad idea for this, how could it be done better?

EDIT: In my process file naming is unique, so I'd never have two different images witht the same name. But there might be a copy of the same image on both computers. Hence the question is about file access or write problems.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: This sounds like an invitation to chaos. Certainly, `rsync` is not designed to be used like this, and it's unlikely to handle conflicts well.

Comment: That would depend on what your restore looks like. It's usually not a good idea to have the same backup directory contain files from multiple sources - so is it really backup?